# How can I perfectly center an image in a window using Slick2d?

Tags: java, slick, image

Dividing the window's width by two to position it in the middle of the x-axis did not work.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Not only do you have to divide the window's width and height in half, but you also have to divide the *image's* dimensions in half. Pseudocode would resemble something like this:

```
// Center image in middle of screen.
image.setCoordinates((screenWidth / 2) - (image.Width / 2)), ((screenHeight / 2) - (image.Height / 2))
```

Comment: @Stync No problem, however I do think you could've probably done this on your own without having to write a question about it :)